# What CSS property controls this effect with Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When clicking and holding a button, a blue ring appears on the outside of the button. I have tried to edit a lot of different properties in button:focus and button:active to change this color to white, but cannot figure out what specifically I am supposed to edit. Gif below of the problem

Any help?

> https://i.gyazo.com/806fa9dc66c1360861ddca05535e34b8.mp4

Fixed. For anyone wondering, you need to edit .btn:active:focus , then set border color. Not just .btn:active or .btn:focus.

Comment: the actual site would be better cant do much with a gif

Comment: Have you tried setting `button:focus { outline: none; }` ?

Comment: Andy, yes I tried that and it has not worked. I did try adding !important to it as well.

Comment: GifCo, would love to but cannot share much of the actual code due to very strict (read: unfair) work policies.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, such a question is not https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Without seeing your html and CSS, we can only wild-guess and answers are not likely to be helpful for others since the problem is not stated clearly

Answer (score 0):

This is bootstrap's CSS rule:

```
button:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(38,143,255,.5);
}
```

Change it to:

```
button:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem white;
}
```

Comment: Avraham, thank you for the help, but that just made a thick white ring around the unactive button and the thin blue ring when focused still remains.